# Toggle buttons not working on phone but works on PC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am just new here, I'm just a beginner at all these stuff so please bear with me. Could you please help me?

I am making an offline website as a school project using Bootstrap.
Everything works fine when I view my site on my laptop and on other PC but the problem occurs when I try to view it on my phone. The toggle buttons (Nav Bar toggle button, Carousel buttons, etc.) are not working when I access the offline website using my phone (via the stock HTML Viewer). I am thinking that the problem has something to do with JavaScript but I believe I put all the files to their respective folders. I am

If it would mean anything, here's an excerpt of my code being only about the Nav Bar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>Learn-IT-Online.com | Home</title>

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Template styles -->
    <style rel="stylesheet">
        /* TEMPLATE STYLES */
        /* Necessary for full page carousel*/
        
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        /* Navigation*/
        
        .navbar {
            background-color: transparent;
        }
        
        .top-nav-collapse {
            background-color: #304a74;
        }
        
        footer.page-footer {
            background-color: #304a74;
        }
        
        @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
            .navbar {
                background-color: #4285F4;
            }
        }
        
        .scrolling-navbar {
            -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out, padding .5s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out, padding .5s ease-in-out;
            transition: background .5s ease-in-out, padding .5s ease-in-out;
        }
        /* Carousel*/
        
        .carousel {
            height: 95%;
        }
        
        @media (max-width: 776px) {
            .carousel {
                height: 100%;
            }
        }
        
        .carousel-item,
        .active {
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        .carousel-inner {
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        /*Caption*/
        
        .flex-center {
            color: #fff;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>


    <!--Navbar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-dark fixed-top scrolling-navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                <img src="img/logo-small.png"></a>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav1">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html" style="text-shadow: 3px 3px 6px indigo;"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="about.html" style="text-shadow: 3px 3px 6px indigo;"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> About</a>
                    </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown btn-group">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="text-shadow: 3px 3px 6px indigo;"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Study...</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                               <a class="dropdown-item" href="modules_intro.html">Introduction: What is Information Technology?</a>
                               <a class="dropdown-item" href="modules_historyofIT.html">The History of Information Technology</a>
                               <a class="dropdown-item" href="modules_whytakeIT.html">Why Take I.T? Some PROS and CONS...</a>
                               <a class="dropdown-item" href="modules_ITjobs.html">Some of the popular jobs in IT: Top 10</a>
                               <a class="dropdown-item" href="modules_basic-essentials-diffproglangs.html">Basic Essentials: Different Programming Languages</a>
                               <a class="dropdown-item" href="modules_index.html"><font color="blue">...More at the Modules Index</font></a>

                            </div>
                        </li>

                </ul>
                <ul>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="btn btn-info" style="text-shadow: 3px 3px 6px indigo;" href="sign-in.html"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Sign in</a>
                    </li></ul>
                

            </div>
                          <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav1" aria-controls="navbarNav1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--/.Navbar-->
    ...
```

and if it would also mean anything, here's my js scripts.

```
<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tether.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.js"></script>

<script>
new WOW().init();
</script>
```

Oh and one last thing, I am using Mdbootstrap.com's templates.

Comment: I'm not familiar with specific template, but as far as I see the issue is in different events called from mobile and PC. When you click something on PC you get 'click' event. When you're on mobile - you get 'tap' event. So the template (or you) have to take care of this.

Comment: Most probably, your navbar and other elements are being covered by a div that's present later in your coding. To check this, Inspect your concerned element in the browser and try to hover around that element. It'll show which div is taking space around that element.